# CorePlot - How to add label to a limit band?

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am graphing data which has categorical ranges as follows:

Range  --> Category

40-70 --> Low

70-110 -->    Normal

110-140 --> High

CPTLimitBand works great for shading the different regions of a graph based on the data's categorical range, but I couldn't find any way to label a limit band. **I would like to add a label to the limit band so that it is immediately obvious what category each shaded region represents.**

I was unable to find anything on SO and the CorePlot API doesn't appear to explicitly support labeling limit bands, but perhaps I'm mistaken.

The graph will be resized for portrait and landscape orientations. The only workaround I could think of was adding a subview to the graphHostingView so that it sits behind the graph layer, but that doesn't seem ideal.

I've attached an image of how I would like to label the limiting bands.

[Graph with labeled limit bands for Low, Normal, and High values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWV1v.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use plot space annotations to label the limit bands. Use a `CPTTextLayer` as the `contentLayer` for the annotation.

Comment: I added a plot space annotation to my graph, and it creates the effect I need for a stationary plot. However, if I use the plot space annotation on a scrollable graph, I'll need to update the plot space annotation every time the plot range changes. Is there an easier way to label the limit band (almost like a legend) and have the label remain omnipresent as the plot is scrolled?

Comment: If the graph only scrolls in one direction (e.g., horizontal or vertical), use a layer annotation instead. Otherwise, implement a plot space delegate and update the annotation positions as needed.